# Deploy from Visual Studio Online build to private IIS server

Tags: iis, tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops, alm

Currently I'm building an ASP.NET MVC project using the new Team Foundation Build 2015 (former Build vNext) feature in Visual Studio Online and I can do a successful deployment to an Azure Website easily.

Also I have a private server with Windows Server 2012 and IIS (you can not access it via the Internet) and I wonder if there is any way to make a deployment from my build in Visual Studio Online. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You need to set up a on-premise build server machine and register it to the visual studio online account. Please check steps in this blog for the details: http://myalmblog.com/2014/04/configuring-on-premises-build-server-for-visual-studio-online/